# Is it possible to declare type as constant?

Tags: typescript, types, constants, constraints

I will have several objects with the same property names, e.g.

```
const a = {foo: 111,};
const b = {foo: 222,};
```

So I'd like to have a global type for them, e.g.

```
type T = {foo: number,};
// in another file
const a: T = {foo: 123,};
```

But those objects are supposed to be constant, i.e. their values should not change since the time of their declaration. Is it possible to enforce such thing? So that

```
let a: T = {foo: 123,};
// or 
const a = {foo: 123,};
a.foo = 321;
```

would throw an error.

Is it possible? Something like this:

```
//this is a syntax error
type T = {foo: number,} as const;
```

Thank you.

Comment: `type T = {readonly foo: number};`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate but I cannot find a suitable target...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) property modifier:

```
type T = { readonly foo: number };
//         ~~~~~~~~
const a: T = { foo: 123 };

a.foo = 321; // error on a.foo
```

If you have multiple properties, you can use the [`Readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype) utility type:

```
type T = Readonly<{ foo: number }>;
//       ~~~~~~~~
const a: T = { foo: 123 };

a.foo = 321; // error on a.foo
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeUBOECGATA9gOwBsQoAzHHALijwFcBbAIwlSgF8BuAKE4GN8BnYFAxU4iFGUpQAjACYAzGy6cMAOkkIo82dK5A)